# How to add text over an image in a JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, text, label

Hello I want to create a program that takes information and displays it over an image in a custom location or points that I set for it. I've tried different things but they do not work or display a frame. Basically, I am wondering how to add text over the image. Thanks!

```
/*
 * This program will ask information to be displayed in four different pieces of documentation.
 */

package choice.assignment;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/*
 * @author Talha
 */

public class ChoiceAssignment extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the type of document you want to receive:");
        if ("passport".equals(option)) {
            String country = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which country's passport would you like?");
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is you name?");
            String countryOfOrigin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is you country of origin?");
            String dateOfBirth = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is your date of birth?");
            new ChoiceAssignment().getPassport(option, country, name, countryOfOrigin, dateOfBirth);
        }
    }

    public void getPassport(String option, String country, String name, String countryOfOrigin, String dateOfBirth) {
        if ("usa".equals(country)) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            frame.setTitle("USA Passport");
            frame.setSize(300, 400);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("uspassport.jpg"));
            panel.add(label);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> custom location or points that I set for it.

You can add a JLabel to the label containing your image. Since you want to randomly position the text you will need to manage the size/location of the text yourself:

```
JLabel text = new JLabel("Some text");
text.setSize( label.getPreferredSize() );
text.setLocation(...);
label.add( text );
```

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. Swing will paint the label with its Icon and then any child components added to the label. Notice my code uses two labels? If you have problems, then update your code with a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is for your question you need a JFrame, a JLabel with an image and a JLabel with text. Add the label with text to the label with the image as shown above. Then add the label with the image to the frame. The `SSCCE` will be about 10-15 lines of code to test the concept